# How to zoom only background image

Tags: css, sass

I struggle with **zoom effect** only for **background image**. This code zoom all elements of **"banner" class**, but I want only make infinite zoom for my background image.

***index.html.erb***

```
<div class="banner">
    <h1>START YOUR JOURNEY</h1>
    <h1>TO HEALTHY LIFE</h1>
</div>
```

***application.css.scss***

```
.banner{
      height:100vh;
      background: url(image-path('swim.jpg')) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      padding-top: 10em;

      -webkit-animation: zoom 50s;
      animation: zoom 50s;

      @keyframes zoom {
         from {
              transform: scale(1,1);
         }
         to {
              transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
         }
      }

      h1{
        font-size: 5.5em;
        margin:0;
        color:$white;
        padding-bottom: .3em;
      }
    }/*banner */
```

jsfiddle code:
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdnx1488/1/)
Zoom effect doesn't work on jsfiddle, but I want to know how to style only background image?

Comment: Provide a codepen or fiddle to better understand..

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute method.[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/978nvycy/)

```
.parent {
  width: 400px; 
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
 }

 .child {
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: black; /* fallback color */
   background-image:  url("https://s22.postimg.org/h6qgvklpd/html5.png");
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   transition: all .5s;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

for reference [Article on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/)